# Nginx as reverse proxy for Gitblit with client certificate authentication. Peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, authentication, git, client-certificate

We used the nginx as reverse proxy for the gitblit with client certificate authentication.

Given the nginx configuration as below.

```
server {
listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
server_name  _;

charset utf-8;

ssl_certificate      D:\cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  D:\key.pem;

ssl_session_cache    off;
ssl_session_timeout  1h;
ssl_buffer_size 8192;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

ssl_client_certificate D:\Program\GitBlit\gitblit-1.8.0\data\certs\ca.pem;
ssl_verify_client optional;

ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
proxy_intercept_errors on;          

location /git {
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:1111;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    
    proxy_ssl_verify off;
    proxy_ssl_name $host;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
}
}
```

The `ssl_verify_client optional;` make the web client requires the client certificate when navigating to https://my_server/git. But I got 502 bad gateway error. The nginx error log as below and no any error log seen from gitblit.

```
2023/10/25 14:48:14 [error] 29404#2072: *43 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /git/ HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:1111/git/", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

I have make sure that if I navigate to the https://127.0.0.1:1111/git and provide the same client certificate, the authentication works well. The gitblit SSL certificate is signed to my_server by a self-signed CA(The D:\Program\GitBlit\gitblit-1.8.0\data\certs\ca.pem for the ssl_client_certificate).

Is this cause by the nginx failed to recognize the SSL certificate from gitblit or failed to pass the client certificate for the authentication?